# apt-get update: Temporary failure resolving '*.debian.org' In Docker Container

Tags: docker

I am on CentOS 8.

The second step in my Dockerfile tries to update the system, but for some reason, it keeps saying that it is having trouble resolving `deb.debian.org` and `security.debian.org`, so the update fails.

```
Step 2/13 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install
 ---> Running in fa042e27e301
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I tried pinging the domains it failed to resolve and it worked, so I'm confused on why it fails in the container.

I then tried creating a docker container from Debian without any other commands. Once in the new container, the same issue occurs (can't update system), then I try pinging `deb.debian.org` & `google.com`, both times it spits out this error (when I did the same thing but on an alpine container, the ping worked, so something is wrong specifically with Debian):

```
ping: deb.debian.org: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

My `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
    "dns": ["1.1.1.1", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

I have a VM with basically the same configuration, to test out containers before publishing them on my host pc. The error I'm getting above happened on my VM, but after a reboot, it fixed itself. After rebooting the host pc, the error persists.

Comment: I have the same problem in MacOs on docker build. have you found the solution?

Comment: @Yuseferi The problem for me was that I was on an OS that wasn't officially supported by Docker, I moved to one that was. You might have more luck finding an answer if you make another question for your specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the network on the VM is not communicating with the default network created by docker during the build (bridge), so try "host" network :

```
docker build --network host -t [image_name]
```

Answer (score 2):

This would allow networking to masquerade that of the host:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

You could also disable `firewalld`, but this is the more friendly solution in my opinion.

Comment: I ran a webserver, so I think I would have had those ports open, but I can't remember anymore. I ended up going down to CentOS 7, I'll just be waiting until Docker has full support on 8.

Comment: Any alternative solution for Ubuntu?